# AssociationTypeMismatch with Rails form using Simple_form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

Hello everyone: I'm trying to solve a problem with my form.

I have a product model where every product has one brand.

I'm using simple_form to create/update my products. In my original version I use

```
= simple_form_for [:admin, product] do |form|
...
= form.association :brand
...
```

Now I add a jquery select with ajax data loading and I change my input to:

```
= form.input_field :brand, input_html: { class: 'form-control select2' }
```

When I save my form I have an error:

```
ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch in Admin::ProductsController#create
Brand(#70355202593700) expected, got String(#70355134114860)
```

In my post params 'brand' is now a string equivalent to the ID of the brand I associate to my product, and I don't know how to fix the association.

Any hint?

Answer (score 0):

For your input_field, it would probably need to be :brand_id because it's no longer being built as an association (that only works with the .association method).

If you are on Rails 3, be sure :brand_id is added to your model's attr_accessible expression.

Comment: If I change brand to brand_id I lose the select, I don't know why.
My html change to `<input class="numeric integer optional form-control form-control form-control form-control form-control" id="product_brand_id" input_html="{:class=&gt;&quot;form-control select2&quot;}" name="product[brand_id]" step="1" type="number">`

Comment: that should've registered when I wrote my first reply ... my bad:
My sense is you will want to use the form.select_tag method and not form.input_field. select_tag(:brand_id, option_tags) or a related method such as options_for_select.

Comment: I try also with ` = form.input_field :brand_id, as: :integer, input_html: { class: 'form-control select2' }` but it doesn't work, I lose my select that becomes a numeric input.

Comment: @kraig.kaminsky I'm using jquery Select2 with remote data: my ajax is working and it returns in the select field a string with the ID of the brand. 

If I change brand to brand_id my select doesn't work, simple_form change my input field in a numeric input.